# Javascript/AJAX action not functioning on every instance within @foreach loop (MVC C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 javascipt/AJAX calls that are made on ahrefs within a @foreach loop.

Essentially, 4 buttons are created in a grid for each row in the "device" table.

The script is posting to an MVC controller. It works fine for the first set of buttons, but then does nothing for the second set?! I am sure I am missing something simple! Some advice would be most appreciated! Thanks Anton

```
 @model Alfred.Models.DashboardModel

@{ var IconColour = "";}
<div class="content">
@foreach (var Location in Model.Location)
{
    <section id="@Location.Section">
        @foreach (var Device in Model.Devices)
            {
                if (Device.LocationId == Location.ID)
                {
                    if (Device.StateId == 1)
                    { IconColour = Device.IconColour; }
                    else
                    { IconColour = "#A0A0A0"; }
                    <div class="mediabox">
                        <div align="center">
                            <a id="UpdateState" data-deviceid="@Device.ID"><i class="@Device.Icon" style="color: @IconColour"></i></a>
                            <div class="mediaboxbtn">
                                <div class="mediaboxbtnl">
                                    <a id="IncreaseLevel" data-deviceid="@Device.ID"><i class="@Device.Button1" style="color: @Device.Button1Colour"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mediaboxbtnm">
                                    @Device.Level
                                </div>
                                <div class="mediaboxbtnr">
                                    <a id="DecreaseLevel" data-deviceid="@Device.ID"><i class="@Device.Button3" style="color: @Device.Button3Colour"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div align="center"><h3>@Device.Name</h3></div>
                    </div>
            }
        }
    </section>
}
</div><!-- /content -->
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UpdateState').click(function () {
        var url = "/Dashboard/ChangeState";
        var DeviceId = $(this).attr('data-deviceid');
        console.log('Data ' + DeviceId);
        $.post(url, { DeviceId }, function (data)
        {
            window.location.reload ();
        });
    })

$('#IncreaseLevel').click(function () {
    var url = "/Dashboard/IncreaseLevel";
    var DeviceId = $(this).attr('data-deviceid');
    console.log('Data ' + DeviceId);
        $.post(url, { DeviceId }, function (data)
        {
            window.location.reload ();
        });
})

$('#DecreaseLevel').click(function () {
  var url = "/Dashboard/DecreaseLevel";
  var DeviceId = $(this).attr('data-deviceid');
  console.log('Data '+ DeviceId);
     $.post(url, { DeviceId }, function (data) {
        window.location.reload();
         });
        })

})
</script>
}
```

Comment: Your generating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes. Use class name instead

Comment: And there is absolutely no point using ajax when you then do a `window.location.reload();`! -

Comment: Stephen is right. `<a class="UpdateState">` and then `$('.UpdateState').click(function () { });` to listen to all buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generating invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes and the `$('#UpdateState')` selector will only ever return the first element with `id="UpdateState"`. Instead use class names. Your html should be

```
<a class="UpdateState" data-deviceid="@Device.ID"><i class="@Device.Icon" style="color: @IconColour"></i></a>
```

and change the script to

```
$('.UpdateState').click(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("ChangeState", "Dashboard")'; // don't hard code your url's
    var DeviceId = $(this).data('deviceid'); // use the data method
    $.post(url, { DeviceId: DeviceId }, function (data) // correct way to pass the data assuming your method parameter is named DeviceId
    {
        ....
    });
})
```

However, using ajax if your then just going to reload the whole page is a bit pointless and defeats the whole purpose of using ajax. You have not shown your controller code, but assuming your wanting to toggle an objects state (true/false) then your method should be updating the database and returning a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise (e.g. `return Json(true)` or `return Json(null);`) Then you can test the return value and update the DOM (for example you might toggle a class name to alter the color of the element to visually indicate its current state)

Comment: Stephen. Thanks for the response, your suggestion worked perfectly! You are absolulely right it is pointless to just refresh the page, I added this as intermediary step to allow me to test the controller logic and make sure my state is changing under all of the correct conditions (basically to save me hitting refresh a lot). I have only just learnt about AJAX and JSON, but I am capturing a result in my controller and I fully plan on returning the JSON result and using it to indicate a changed state (maybe using Knockout?).

Comment: Can't really see any point in using Knockout for that. Also its not really clear why you have a property `IconColour`. Assuming you have 2 colors, say red and green to indicate the state, then it would be easier to use css from styling and in the success call back, use the `.toggleClass()` function

Comment: The property IconColour reads from the devices table in the database. Different devices have different IconColours. I am using the IconColour to indicate to the user that the device is on. So for example, if the device is a light, then the IconColour is set to yellow, if its speakers then the IconColour is set to black, there could be upto 30/40 different devices and thus different colours. The off value is always grey. I have not come across .toggleClass() yet (this is my first ever proper coding project), so I will have a look into that. Thanks.

Comment: OK. I get it now. You could just add a style in your css file say `.off { color: grey; }` and then if you use `$(...).toggleClass('off')` it will add the class and change the color to grey. If you then use `.toggleClass('off')` again, it will remove the class and the color will revert back to its original value.